# Unstaging a file with git reset without specifying HEAD

Tags: git

When unstaging a file in git, the recommended way is to do:

```
git reset HEAD <file>
```

However, I find that this also works:

```
git reset <file>
```

Why is `HEAD` needed in the first case, if the second one appears to also work and is shorter to type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't. According to this [git-reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) documentation:

> The `<commit>` defaults to HEAD in all forms.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that obvious little piece which is inconspicuously placed at the edge of the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The man-page clearly states that "The `<tree-ish>/<commit>` argument defaults to HEAD in all forms." So the second form is equivalent to the first. If you are wondering why `git status` recommends the second form it seems to make sense to me to provide a full version without using any defaults, especially for new users. But your view of didactic might be different.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the "it isn't" answer, what happens if you have a file named `zoop` and a branch named `zoop` and you enter:

```
git reset zoop
```

Is the `zoop` argument a branch name, or a file name?

What if you enter:

```
git reset zoop zoop
```

?  What about if you use the form:

```
git reset -- zoop
```

?  (Make a little dummy repo and experiment with these to see what happens.)